# UI Testing Failure - No matches found for MenuItems

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, xcode-ui-testing

Error:UI Testing Failure - No matches found for MenuItems

```
  UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = constant.password

  enterPasswordTextField.doubleTap()

  // Tap the Paste button to input the password
  app.menuItems["Paste"].tap()
```

I have written this code in my test case , i have even tried disabling hardware keyboard for the simulator but still the doubletap() function is not working.

I am using Xcode 7.3.1.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to add an expectation for the menuItem to appear. Note that `doubleTap()` will work only if the textfield already has focus, so you should add an additional `tap()` before double tapping

```
    let app = XCUIApplication()

    UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = "hello"

    let enterPasswordTextField = app.textFields["textField"]
    enterPasswordTextField.tap()

    expectationForPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "count > 0"), evaluatedWithObject: app.menuItems, handler: nil)
    enterPasswordTextField.doubleTap()
    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(10.0, handler: nil)

    app.menuItems["Paste"].tap()
```

Bear in mind that it might not be the best idea to use access the menuitem with the localised test, as it may fail on a device on non-english devices. Therefore you should use a most sophisticated logic to determine the location of the paste menu item. For starters, **in the oversimplified hypothesis that the textfield is empty**, you may want to replace

```
app.menuItems["Paste"].tap()
```

with

```
app.menuItems.elementsBoundByIndex(2).tap()
```

Comment: Hi Tomas thank you for the answer but it is still not working .

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Hi Tomas thank you for the answer but it is still not working .  I have tried the same code and still getting error and i want to double tap SecureTextField .(not normal TextField)                                                                                                        Error :Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout of 10 seconds, with unfulfilled expectations: "Expect predicate `count > 0` for object <XCUIElementQuery: 0x7fb148f1cd60>".

Comment: I tried this also ..MenuItems option not popped up in the simulator ..i tried by disabling Hardware keyboard but still double tap() is not working for SecureTextFeilds.

Comment: You should execute test code step by step to see if the `tap` and `doubleTap` methods are executed properly. Check that after running `tap` the textfield gets focus and that after `doubleTap` you see the menu item

Comment: TextField had the focus but double tap didn't work.Something is wrong with doubleTap() method.

Comment: There's something specific with your setup, I tried the posted code on a black project and it works properly. Post back if you find what's going on

Comment: @ThomasCamin - Thank you!! This really helped me

Answer (score 0):

Do two taps separately - one to give focus to the text field and then one to bring up the menu items.

Observe that if you do a double tap with the speed of a double click on an inactive text field, the pasteboard menu does not appear, so just try separating the action into two separate parts. If you need to, add a sleep command between each tap.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58246279/9109530

when isSecureTextEntry = true you should use app.secureTextFields instead app.textFields like as below line

```
let passwordField = app.secureTextFields["password"]
```